# Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (4): x, y, colour

Tags: r, ggplot2

So I know that there are already a few threads on this error, but unfortunately it looks like every other answer is specific to the individual person's problem, and I'm not seeing anyone address *why* this problem is coming up.

With the below code, I keep getting the following error:
"Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (4): x, y, colour"

I am looking to mark 3 cities on a map and make point size correlate to population size of the city.

Could someone explain why I keep getting this error? The code works if I remove the "population" field from my data frame.

```
longitude <- c(98.98172,100.5018,98.33809)
latitude <- c(18.70606,13.75633,7.951933)
names <- c("Chiang Mai", "Bangkok", "Phuket")
population<-c(148447,8281000,386605)

M<-rbind(longitude,latitude,names,population)

tlocations<-data.frame(M)


travel_map <- get_map("Bangkok", zoom=6, source = "google", maptype="terrain")


ggmap(travel_map) + geom_point(data=tlocations,aes(x=longitude,y=latitude,color="Red"),size=population)
```

Comment: Your dataset appears to be transposed (rows as column and columns as rows).  This means that your dataset is 4 rows long, but the variable `longitude` has only 3 values.  That's where the `length` error comes from; there is a mismatch between the data and the variable.  To create your `data.frame` try `data.frame(longitude, latitude, names, population)`.  You'll also want to move `size` inside `aes`.

Comment: That's huge - it worked. Thanks a lot! And thanks for explaining the reasoning behind it too. Very much appreciated.